# Where does bazel store fetched packages?

Tags: package, bazel

In my `WORKSPACE` file I have defined a http_archive like

```
http_archive(
    name = "awscli_zip",
    urls = [
        "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-{version}.zip".format(version = awscli_version)
    ],
    sha256 = awscli_sha256,
    build_file = "//third_party:BUILD.awscli",
)
```

When I am now running `bazel clean && bazel fetch @awscli_zip//...` it fetches 1 package as seen here:

```sh
INFO: All external dependencies fetched successfully.
Loading: 1 packages loaded
```

When I am looking into the directory where the `WORKSPACE` file is located, usually bazel provides multiple `bazel-*` files where I can inspect the last build/test. I would assume that bazel also stores fetched packages there. Unfortunately no such directories are created.

So where exactly does bazel store fetched packages if not in the bazel output directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `$(bazel info output_base)/external`.

(The "convenience symlinks", as the `bazel-*` symlinks in the workspace root as are known, are only created on build or test commands.)